# Black screen installing Ubuntu 12.04 on HP pavilion g6

Tags: installation

I m trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my HP pavilion g6 via Live USB using UNetbootin, but after selecting my flash to boot from, if  I select Try Ubuntu without installing or Install Ubuntu on the Live USB menu the screen of my laptop turns black. Please, can anyone knows what s happening here and how can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using the "nomodeset" kernel boot parameter. You need to modify the boot options upon booting from your Live USB drive to add this option, which should then allow you to reach a graphical desktop in order to install.

Please note that in my example I am using the 32-bit 12.04.3 ISO:

1. Boot from your Live USB.
2. Press a key as soon as you see the brown screen with the small logo at the bottom.
3. Select a language from the menu once it appears.
4. Press F6 and use the cursor keys to highlight and select "nomodeset" on the small grey menu.
5. Press the escape key to clear this menu, then press enter on "Try Ubuntu..."

More information on how to do this can be found here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

It's likely the laptop you mention is using a graphics chip which will require some proprietary graphics drivers to be installed in order to function normally. However, try the above first to see how you get on.

Good luck!